# $S=\frac{.3450}{1+12.85e^{-1.24 t}}$ find $S'$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$S=\frac{.3450}{1+12.85e^{-1.24t}}$$

find $S'$

---

wolfram alpha is saying that

$$\frac{dS}{dt}=\frac{5.49723e^{1.24 t}}{(12.85+e^{1.24 t})^2}$$

my attempt

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dS}{dt}
   &=.3450 \cdot \dfrac{d}{dt} (1+12.85e^{-1.24 t})^{-1} 
  \\[10pt] &=0.3450\, (-1)(1+12.85e^{-1.24 t})^{-2} \cdot 12.85 e^{-1.24t}\cdot(-1.24)
\\[10pt] &= \frac{.3450\cdot12.85\cdot1.24e^{-1.24t}}{(1+12.85e^{-1.24t})^2}
\end{aligned}
 $$

Comment: You seemed to be useing lower-case $s$ and capital $S$ synonymously. I corrected that.

Comment: Are you sure that is what the OP meant?  I don't think the lower case should ever have been written at all (it was never defined).  It should read as $\frac{dS}{dt}=.3450 \cdot \frac{d (1+12.85e^{-1.24 t})^{-1}}{dt} $, I believe.  I'm assuming the OP was assuming that $s =  (1+12.85e^{-1.24 t})^{-1} = \frac S{.3450}$.

Comment: Did you actually check to see if those are actually different answers?  Because they aren't.

Comment: Just multiply top and bottom by $e^{2*1.24t}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{aligned}
\frac{dS}{dt}
   &=.3450 \cdot \frac{ds}{dt} (1+12.85e^{-1.24 t})^{-1} 
  \\[10pt] &=.3450\cdot(-1)(1+12.85e^{-1.24 t})^{-2} \cdot 12.85 e^{-1.24t}\cdot(-1.24)
\\[10pt] &= \frac{.3450\cdot12.85\cdot1.24e^{-1.24t}}{(1+12.85e^{-1.24t})^2}
\end{aligned}$

Which in turn equals:

$\frac{.3450\cdot12.85\cdot1.24e^{-1.24t}}{(1+12.85e^{-1.24t})^2}=$

$\frac{.3450\cdot12.85\cdot1.24e^{1.24t}}{e^{2*1.24t}(1+12.85e^{-1.24t})^2}=$

$\frac{.3450\cdot12.85\cdot1.24e^{1.24t}}{(e^{1.24t}+12.85)^2}=$

$\frac {5.49723e^{1.24t}}{(e^{1.24t}+12.85)^2}$

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is quite right.  Note that $0.345\cdot12.85\cdot1.24=5.49723$.

Comment: I think the OP meant for the sign of the exponentials, that is, WA's correct simplification of the expression

Comment: @Moo One can fix this by multiplying the fraction by $\dfrac{e^{2.48t}}{e^{2.48t}}$.

Comment: @projectilemotion: Yes, this is fairly obvious, but I was just addressing where I thought the OPs issue arose.

Answer (score 2):

From [@HenryTuring's work](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562133/s-frac-3450112-85e-1-24-t-find-s/2562141#2562141):
$$\left(\frac{A}{B + Ce^{-\alpha t}}\right)'=\frac{\alpha  A C e^{-\alpha t}}{\left(B+C e^{-\alpha t}\right)^2}$$
Now we can multiply both the top and bottom with $\left(e^{\alpha t}\right)^2$ to get:
$$\frac{\alpha  A C e^{-\alpha t} \left(e^{-\alpha t}\right)^2}{\left(B+C e^{-\alpha t}\right)^2 \left(e^{\alpha t}\right)^2}=\frac{\alpha  A C e^{-\alpha t}e^{2\alpha t}}{\left(B+C e^{-\alpha t}\right)^2 e^{2\alpha t}}=\frac{\alpha  A C e^{2\alpha t-\alpha t}}{\left(B+C e^{-\alpha t}\right)^2 e^{2\alpha t}}=\frac{\alpha  A C e^{\alpha t}}{\left(B+C e^{-\alpha t}\right)^2 e^{2\alpha t}}=\frac{\alpha  A C e^{\alpha t}}{\left(\left(B+C e^{-\alpha t}\right)\left(e^{\alpha t}\right)\right)^2}=\frac{\alpha  A C e^{\alpha t}}{\left(Be^{\alpha t}+C e^{\alpha t}e^{-\alpha t}\right)^2}=\frac{\alpha ACe^{\alpha t}}{\left(B e^{\alpha t}+C\right)^2}$$
So **your answer is correct**.

Comment: +1 Because of the complete proof! I was too lazy to write it all, lol.

Comment: +1 because this fully addresses the OP's concern that he/she did not obtain the same answer as Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from numbers, your function is in the form

$$f(t) =\large  \frac{A}{B + Ce^{-\alpha t}}$$

hence its derivative, easy to compute, is

$$f'(t) = \large \frac{\alpha  A C e^{-\alpha t}}{\left(B+C e^{-\alpha t}\right)^2}$$

Know this, and the numerical part will be a piece of cake.

Comment: But the OP's computation is clearly correct and consistent with your answer.

Comment: @projectilemotion He compute the derivative whilst inserting the numerical valued during the process. To avoid any possible error, besides the approximation ones, methinks it was useful to provide the pure analytical evaluation of the derivative. It's then easier to put the numbers at the end. Different approach, same result. It's a sort of didactical idea for his future homework.

Comment: While I absolutely agree, IMO it is worth saying that you can obtain the same as Wolfram|Alpha's answer by multiplying the numerator and denominator by $e^{2\alpha t}$, since this is what the OP's primary confusion was (That he/she did not get a consistent answer with WA).

Comment: @projectilemotion About that, then I have a single absolute advice: Wolfram Alpha sucks. It's full of bugs, and many times it gave wrong results. One thing is W. Mathematica, but Alpha is really terrible. Now that I know this, I'm even happier I wrote the analytical form xD